# RMI error while trying to get an applet from the server

Tags: java, applet, rmi

I'm working on a simple RMI example, the client will basically try calling an applet from the server. So I've defined an class called "simpleApplet" (the extends Applet), on the client side I have two files: the java files of the server interface and the one for the client code. On the server side, I have three files: One for my applet, one for the server interface and one for the implementation. 
The server runs fine, but I get an error on the client side, here it is:

> java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested
>   exception is:     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: simpleApplet (no
>   security manager: RMI class loader disabled)

I think there's an issue with my applet object, it's not recognized by the client, I tried using casts (with Applet) but I still have an issue. Would you happen to know how to solve this problem ? 
Thanks !

Here is the client side code

```
public class SwingCall {

    static Applet a;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        myRmiServerIntf obj = (myRmiServerIntf) Naming.lookup("rmi://10.100.162.203:1100/newRmiServer");
        a= (Applet) obj.getApplet();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Window");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        JButton button = new JButton("Call applet");
        panel.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new Action1());

    }

    static class Action1 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            a.init();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("myApplet");
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setSize(500, 500);
            frame.getContentPane().add(a);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the server side code:

```
public class myRmiServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements myRmiServerIntf {

        public static final String MESSAGE = "Hello World";

        public myRmiServer() throws RemoteException {
            super(0);    // required to avoid the 'rmic' step, see below
        }

        public Applet getApplet() {
            simpleApplet app= new simpleApplet();
            return (Applet)app;
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("RMI server started");

            try { //special exception handler for registry creation
                LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1101); 
                System.out.println("java RMI registry created.");
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                //do nothing, error means registry already exists
                System.out.println("java RMI registry already exists.");
            }

            //Instantiate RmiServer
            myRmiServer obj = new myRmiServer();
            System.out.println("After");
            // Bind this object instance to the name "newRmiServer"
            Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:1101/newRmiServer", obj);
            System.out.println("PeerServer bound in registry");
        }
}
```

And here is the applet code:

```
public class simpleApplet extends Applet {

    JLabel l= new JLabel("120");

    public void init() {

        super.resize(500, 200);
        super.add(l);
        super.init();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `simpleApplet` class file needs to be deployed at the client.

Comment: But if I do that my whole program would be useless, the client would be able to get the applet without having to access the server

Comment: Correct. So maybe your whole program *is* useless. Unless you use the RMI codebase feature, you can't do this.

Comment: Or maybe you should be writing a Web page instead of a client, which is what applets are (or were) really for.